# Remove keywords from code 'listings'

Tags: listings, color

I tried to customize a code listing to support some pseudo-code format that suited me best. It was easy to add keywords using `otherkeywords` or `morekeywords`, but the opposite, the `deletekeywords` did not work as expected. If the stem of a word was defined as a keyword, the word would be highlighted. For example, if *create* is in `morekeywords`, then *created* is also highlighted except the *d* in the end. Adding created to the `deletekeywords` list is not helping.

Please suggest how I could solve this problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} %Windows-1252 encoding
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    basicstyle=\sffamily\tiny,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    frame=single,
    columns=fullflexible
    }

\begin{document}

\title{}
\author{}

\maketitle

\section{somesection}

\lstset{language=Python, caption=somecaption, otherkeywords={smooth}, deletekeywords={smoothed, is, not}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{lstlisting}
    smooth is welcome
    smoothed is not
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: You are right. It is my mistake. I have added code.

Comment: If you use `keywords={smooth}` instead, everything works fine. Moreover, `otherkeywords` is defined for keywords containing non-letter elements. Is there any reason why you're using `otherkeywords`?

Comment: Very silly of me! I did not realize I could use `keywords`. I thought `otherkeywords` or `morekeywords` is the one I should use to add more keywords to the set. Thank you very much!

Comment: I looked into it a bit, and `keywords` is not what I want, because it resets the list of keywords and the ones listed inside `keywords` are the only keywords that get highlighted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather use `keywords={smooth}` instead of `otherkeywords`. According to the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), the latter

> defines keywords that contain other characters, or start with digits.

Here's an updated MWE showing the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    basicstyle=\sffamily\tiny,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
    frame=single,
    columns=fullflexible
    }

\begin{document}

\title{}
\author{}

\maketitle

\section{somesection}

\lstset{language=Python, caption=somecaption, keywords={smooth}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{lstlisting}
    smooth is welcome
    smoothed is not
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}​
```

The above MWE specifies the `keyword`s, but subsequently also overwrites the existing keywords supported by the `language` setting. To maintain the existing set and add more/remove some, use `morekeywords={smooth}, deletekeywords={is,not}`.

Comment: I thought there was a problem with using `keywords` as this resest the existing `keywords` and hence the reason for `otherkeywords`?

Comment: That is exactly what I was about to comment on. Using only `keywords` seems to remove all Python keywords, which I do not want. That was the reason I used `otherkeywords` to begin with.

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta: I've updated my answer with the use of `morekeywords={smooth},deletekeywords={is,not}`, which seems to be what you're after.